# mvc collection in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a situation I'd never run into before where I have a collection inside of my model, but I'm only displaying for one item at a time. Here's a quick example...

**Model:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    //some other fields

    public IList<SomeObject> MyCollection { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model MyViewModel

<ul>
    for(int i; i < Model.MyCollection.Count(); i++)
    {
        //user can select an item from list and for the chosen item,
        //show fields to edit below

        <li>@Model.MyCollection[i].Name;
    }
</ul>

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyCollection[TempData["Index"]].SomeProperty)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyCollection[TempData["Index"]].SomeProperty)

//other fields
```

This is contained in a form in a partial view that refreshes when the user selects an item from the list of names and their selection is reflected in `TempData["Index"]`.

My issue is that when I post this to my controller, which expects `MyViewModel model`, the collection of `MyCollection` inside will only show one item (whichever was displayed for). To capture the entire collection, must I loop through the entire collection and use hidden fields for each object that isn't the currently selected one (it's quite a complex model) or is there a better way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `ViewModels` are not `ViewState`, in the sense that all of it is posted back to the server as Asp.Net WebForms did.

If in your scenario you have different information that is flowing from Controller -> View (when rendering the page) than from View -> Controller (when posting), then you should actually use two separate ViewModels, representing the data differently.

For example, when posting you would probably only post the id of the selected Item, and the controller would internally recreate your `MyViewModel` with the entire collection (probably from a database or something like that).

The view should avoid sending large sets of data that are not actual input from the user.

Now, if you really have no other choice than to resend the entire collection from the view to the controller, then you'll have to create hidden input elements for each item and each property within it.

Comment: +1 I thought about different models but couldn't find a good example of it. Unfortunately, I do have user input to pass back. Would it be possible though to have a single instance of my object on post instead of collection or will it always send a collection with one item?

Comment: Well, you can post whatever you want. Ultimately you'll declare some model as a parameter to your action, and if within the HTTP Post, values match the property names of your parameter object it will be automatically created by the default binder. Remember that a form post knows nothing about objects, it just posts form values. It's the default binder that extracts viewmodels from those values.